# Authenticating with hashed password?

Tags: mysql, .net, hash, passwords

Shorter version:
How to use the MySQL Connector/NET to hash the password when connecting the server?

Instead of hashing it, the connector simply sends the password in clear text (connection string), whether I concatenate the connection string myself or use the MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

In login request to MySQL Server from the Connector, password is not sent in clear text (just traced it with Wireshark). Password is a hash value or encrypted.

Perhaps the "clear text password" is in your program and needs to be saved/stored in a secure way?